# Ajax form submission with Jquery validation plugin is not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I am using Jquery validation plugin to validate form, I need to display success/error message after submission without reloading page. 
But everytime I submit form, page reloads. Also even when data appears on database, "error" alert keeps coming.

index.php

```
<?php
function register() { 
    $name = $_POST['name']; 
    $mail = $_POST['email']; 
    $query = "INSERT INTO table_name (name,email) VALUES ('$name','$email')"; 
    $data = mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error()); 
    echo json_encode($data);
}
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    register();
}
?>
```

Javascript code:

```
$("#myform").validate({
   //rules, messages go here

   submitHandler: function(event) {
        $.ajax({
             url: "index.php",
             type: "POST",
             data: $(#myform).serialize(),
             dataType: 'json',
             success: function() {
                   alert("Thank you!");
             },
             error: function() {
                   alert("Error. Try again please!");
             }
        });

        event.preventDefault();
     } 

});
```

Comment: If page reloads probably your JS code does not get triggered. It could be a JS error, or you are not loading jquery, etc. on the page.

Comment: `$(#myform).serialize()` quotes missing => `$('#myform').serialize()`

Comment: return false in the function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think your problem is here

```
 data: $(#myform).serialize()
```

change it to

```
 data: $(this).serialize()
```